# Need to use a Subquery to display only 'no'

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

As part of a tutorial for uni I have been told to alter the code below so it only displays "'no'" using a sub query.

I have tried using a select statement `subquery` which selects no when grade is = to Max grade however it still displays all values.

```
SELECT `no`,`code`,MAX(`grade`)
    FROM take
    WHERE `no`=(SELECT `no`
        FROM take
                WHERE grade=MAX(`grade`));
```

I expect only the row `no` to be displayed in a table that is connected to the highest grade.

Comment: In your subquery get the row which has 'no' and max grade. Something like `select * from table_a where id in (select id from table_a where code='no' and grade=max(grade))`

Answer (score 0):

You might find a `LIMIT` query to be sufficient:

```
SELECT no, code, grade
FROM take
ORDER BY grade DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This would work well if you only ever expected a single record to have the max grade, or, if there could be ties, you don't care which tie gets returned.  If you want to stick with your subquery approach, then assert the grade, not the `no` value:

```
SELECT no, code, grade
FROM take
WHERE grade = (SELECT MAX(grade) FROM take);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` for this requirement.

```
 select no, code, t2.grade from taket1
 inner join 
    (select max(grade) grade from take) t2 on t2.grade = t1.grade
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT t.no
FROM take t
WHERE t.grade = (SELECT max(t2.grade)
                 FROM take t2
                 WHERE t2.no = t.no
                );
```

That is, you want a correlation clause.  The correlation clause connects `no` in the inner table and outer table.  But the comparison is on `grade`.